# jquery if statment detected the height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i`m trying to change the padding of my h1 , by detected the height of my page , i will change it if my screen height between
 700:800 px  but my code not working :(

```
if ($('.background-wrapper').height() <= 800 && $('.background-wrapper').height() >= 700) {
        $(".login > background-wrapper > h1").css("padding-top", "50px")
    }
```

HTML :

```
<div class="background-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h1> CRM INTERACTIVE MAP SYSTEM</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any reason you are not using CSS Media Queries for this?

Answer (score 2):

Make with CSS media queries

```
@media only screen and (min-height: 700px) and (max-heigth: 800px) {
   .login > background-wrapper > h1 {
      padding-top: 50px;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Media queries is your best choice. See the other answer(s) for that.

In case there's something you're not showing us that might require you to do this in javascript:

`.background-wrapper` isn't going to give you the screen size accurately, It will only give you the height of itself (which could also be the height of the screen in some cases).

What you'll want to use is `$(window).height()` or `window.innerHeight`.

Also as @NiZa has pointed out your selector isn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do it with `media queries` (see @Marcos Pérez Gude answer), you should change some things.

First of all you need to change your `selector`. Remove `>`, because there is a `div` in between. And secondly you could try to put it inside a `$( document ).ready()` function.

Last of all, see Jack's answer. Using `$(window).height()` is better than the div himself.

**Example**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(windo).height() <= 800 && $(window).height() >= 700) {
    $(".login > background-wrapper h1").css("padding-top", "50px")
  }
});
```